# how to show order by and group by together

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        GradeID, Division, vchSubject, Topic, competency, AVG(Column3) as 'Total',
        AVG(Played_Count) as 'KidCount',
        (AVG(Played_Count) / AVG(Column3)) * 100 as 'Percents'
   FROM (
         SELECT UserID, [User Name], GradeID, Division,
                vchSubject,stable.vchCompetency as Topic,
                stable.vchComptencyDesc as competency,
                column3, isnull(column4,0) as 'Played_Count',
                (isnull(column4, 0) / column3 ) * 100 as 'Percents'
           FROM
                (
                --some code
                ) as Mtable4
  GROUP BY Mtable4.GradeID, Division, vchSubject, Topic, competency
  ORDER BY Percents
```

I am newbie to sql query,i am finding difficult to group and ordering ;its give error.can anyone help me to resolve.

Comment: Can you post the error details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this !

```
 ;with mtable4 as
 (
 SELECT DISTINCT
        GradeID, Division, vchSubject, Topic, competency,AVG(Column3) as 'Total',
        AVG(Played_Count) as 'KidCount',
        (AVG(Played_Count) / AVG(Column3)) * 100 as 'Percent'
   FROM (
         SELECT UserID, [User Name], GradeID, Division,
                vchSubject,stable.vchCompetency as Topic,
                stable.vchComptencyDesc as competency, column3,
                isnull(column4, 0) as 'Played_Count',
                (isnull(column4, 0) / column3) * 100 as 'Percents'
           FROM table
        )

 SELECT *
   FROM mtable4
  GROUP BY Mtable4.GradeID, Division, vchSubject, Topic, competency
  ORDER BY Percents
```